# How to implement a ROT13 function in Swift?

Tags: xcode, string, swift, rot13

I would like to create a function that receives a String and returns a String, and that replaces a letter with the letter 13 letters after it in the alphabet (ROT13). I found a lot of examples, unfortunately I was not able to make it work no one because of various errors. For example this one:

```
var key = [String:String]() // EDITED
let uppercase = Array(arrayLiteral: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
let lowercase = Array(arrayLiteral: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
for i in 0 ..< 26 {
    key[uppercase[i]] = uppercase[(i + 13) % 26]
    key[lowercase[i]] = lowercase[(i + 13) % 26]
}

func rot13(s: String) -> String {
    return String(map(s, { key[$0] ?? $0 }))
}
```

Comment: Why not just make the key array a string array?

Comment: You're trying to get an element out of `key` with `$0`, which is a `Character`, not an `Int`

Comment: Thank you. I made the key a string array now. Now there is a problem with the string seq: "extraneous argument label 'seq:' in call"

Comment: I've expanded my answer to generalize it to `rotN` which makes the implementation of `rot13`, `rot47`, `rot5`, the combination of `rot13` and `rot5` straightforward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually your initial approach of mapping `Character`s was good:

```
var key = [Character: Character]()
```

But the two arrays must the be arrays of `Characters`:

```
let uppercase = Array("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters)
let lowercase = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".characters)
```

(*Remark:* You (almost) never want to call a `xxxLiteral:` initializer
explicitly. Doing so is (almost) always hiding the actual problem.)

Now your code to fill the dictionary works:

```
for i in 0 ..< 26 {
    key[uppercase[i]] = uppercase[(i + 13) % 26]
    key[lowercase[i]] = lowercase[(i + 13) % 26]
}
```

And transforming a string can be done as

```
//                       map
// String --> Characters ---> Characters -> String

func rot13(s: String) -> String {
    return String(s.characters.map { key[$0] ?? $0 })
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an alternate version of @AMomchilov's `rot13` which uses a `switch` and less math and eliminates magic numbers:

```
func rot13(_ unicodeScalar: UnicodeScalar) -> Character {
    var result = unicodeScalar.value
    
    switch unicodeScalar {
    case "A"..."M", "a"..."m":
        result += 13
    case "N"..."Z", "n"..."z":
        result -= 13
    default:
        break
    }
    
    return Character(UnicodeScalar(result)!)
}

func rot13(_ input: String) -> String {
    return String(input.unicodeScalars.map(rot13))
}

print(rot13("Uryyb, jbeyq!")) // "Hello, world!"
```

---

**Generalization to rotN**

I've taken the `rot13` functions above and generalized them to `rotN` by having them take an array of `ClosedRange<UnicodeScalar>`.  This allows you to implement `rot13`, `rot47`, `rot5`, and the combination of `rot13` and `rot5` in a very straightforward manner.

```
func rotN(_ unicodeScalar: UnicodeScalar, intervals:[ClosedRange<UnicodeScalar>]) -> Character {
    var result = unicodeScalar.value

    for interval in intervals {
        let half = (interval.upperBound.value - interval.lowerBound.value + 1) / 2
        let halfway = UnicodeScalar(interval.lowerBound.value + half)!

        switch unicodeScalar {
        case interval.lowerBound..<halfway:
            result += half
        case halfway...interval.upperBound:
            result -= half
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    return Character(UnicodeScalar(result)!)
}

func rotN(_ input: String, intervals:[ClosedRange<UnicodeScalar>]) -> String {
    return String(input.unicodeScalars.map {rotN($0, intervals: intervals)})
}

func rot13(_ input: String) -> String {
    return rotN(input, intervals:["A"..."Z", "a"..."z"])
}

func rot47(_ input: String) -> String {
    return rotN(input, intervals:["!"..."~"])
}

func rot5(_ input: String) -> String {
    return rotN(input, intervals:["0"..."9"])
}

func rot13and5(_ input: String) -> String {
    return rotN(input, intervals:["A"..."Z", "a"..."z", "0"..."9"])
}

print(rot13("Uryyb, jbeyq!"))        // "Hello, world!"
print(rot47("%96 BF:4< 3C@H? 7@I"))  // "The quick brown fox"
print(rot5("6 + 7 = 8"))             // "1 + 2 = 3"
print(rot13and5("Whyl 9, 6221"))     // "July 4, 1776"
```

---

Here is a version of `rotN` based upon `@AMomchilov's` original `rot13`:

```
func rotN(_ unicodeScalar: UnicodeScalar, intervals:[ClosedRange<UnicodeScalar>]) -> UnicodeScalar {
    var result = unicodeScalar.value
    
    for interval in intervals {
        let start = interval.lowerBound.value
        let length = interval.upperBound.value - start + 1
        
        if interval ~= unicodeScalar {
            result = (result + length/2 - start) % length + start
        }
    }
    
    return UnicodeScalar(result)!
}

func rotN(_ input: String, intervals:[ClosedRange<UnicodeScalar>]) -> String {
    return String(input.unicodeScalars.map {Character(rotN($0, intervals:intervals))})
}
```

Comment: Ooo this is an interesting approach. I love the switch for range checking. I forgot that was possible; it's so useful! I'm not a fan of the workaround to remove the mod 13 though, because it makes it difficult to generalize this to rotN. I think a better solution would be to factor my 2 math lines into a seperate, parameterized function.

Comment: @AMomchilov, I've taken your challenge and generalized to `rotN` :-).

Comment: Not bad, but I still the pursuit of avoiding `%` is adding unnecessary complexity

Comment: @AMomchilov, I added a `%`-based version based on your original code.  I had changed it to return `Character` to make the calling code simpler.

Comment: I like it! There we go!

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach, which doesn't use a lookup array:

```
let input = "Hello World"

func rot13(unicodeScalar: UnicodeScalar) -> UnicodeScalar {
    var result = unicodeScalar.value

    if 65...90 ~= result { //Detect capital A ... Z
        result = (result + 13 - 65) % 26 + 65
    }
    else if 97 ... 122 ~= result { //Detect lowercase a ... z
        result = (result + 13 - 97) % 26 + 97
    }

    return UnicodeScalar(result)
}

func rot13(_ input: String) -> String {
    let resultUSs = input.unicodeScalars.map(rot13)

    var resultUSV = String.UnicodeScalarView()
    resultUSV.appendContentsOf(resultUSs) //for Swift 2.2
    //resultUSV.append(contentsOf: resultUSs) //for Swift 3.0
    return String(resultUSV)
}

let output = rot13(input)

print(output)
```

Comment: Your Swift 3 is showing.  You might want to note `resultUSV.appendContentsOf(resultUSs)` for Swift 2.2 compatibility.

Comment: Ah yes, I was writing this in IBM's Swift sandbox, which is Swift 3 only

Comment: Yeah, I wish they would let you choose Swift 2.2 vs. Swift 3.  It's going to be transition time for a while until Xcode 8 is GM.

Comment: oops. fixing it now

Comment: One final thing: You need a capital `U` for  `return UnicodeScalar(result)`.

Comment: Thanks ;) fixed it now